# No output from Powershell command when run from script vs cli

Tags: powershell

This one command doesn't write output to the screen when running it in a script, but it works when executing it in the PowerShell ISE cli:

```
$toptenseverity = $csvData | select Severity, Title -Unique | sort Severity -Descending | select -First 11
$toptenseverity
```

Code:

```
Write-Host "`r`nTop 10 most severe vulnerabilities:"
$toptenseverity = $csvData | select Severity, Title -Unique | sort Severity -Descending | select -First 11
$toptenseverity
Write-Host "Trying again to write output of toptenseverity using write host toptenseverity:"
Write-Host $toptenseverity
Write-Host "Trying again to write output of toptenseverity using write output toptenseverity:"
Write-Output $toptenseverity
```

Output:

```
Generating P1 report. Please wait...

Total P1 count:    352
Severity 5 total:  11
Severity 4 total:  16
Severity 3 total:  325

Top 10 most severe vulnerabilities:

Trying again to write output of toptenseverity using write host toptenseverity:
@{Severity=5; YouDon'tNeedToKnowThis} @{Severity=4; Title=YouDon'tNeedToKnowThis} @{Severity=4; Title=YouDon'tNeedToKnowThis
} @{Severity=4; Title=YouDon'tNeedToKnowThis} @{Severity=4; Title=YouDon'tNeedToKnowThis} 
Trying again to write output of toptenseverity using write output toptenseverity:
```

When I run it from the cli in PS ISE I get this output:

```
Severity Title                                                                                  
-------- -----                                                                                  
5        YouDon'tNeedToKnowThis                                                  
4        YouDon'tNeedToKnowThis
4        YouDon'tNeedToKnowThis                                    
4        YouDon'tNeedToKnowThis                             
4        YouDon'tNeedToKnowThis
```

Comment: `$toptenseverity | Format-Table` or `Write-Output $toptenseverity | Format-Table` giving you what you want?

Comment: Write-Output $toptenseverity | Format-Table worked! Thank you. Now, how do I mark your reply as the answer?

Comment: Great! I've submitted properly as answer (comments can't be accepted - just upvoted of flagged)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use:

```
Write-Output $toptenseverity | Format-Table
```

This forces the object to be formatted as a table, which is what's going on in the ISE (by default)